# Explicit construction of Haar measure on a profinite group

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a profinite group.
It is known that in $G$, every neighborhood of the identity element contains an open compact subgroup.
I would like to explicitly construct the Haar measure on $G$.
The Haar measure $\mu$ on $G$ is a measure defined on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(G)$ of all Borel sets with the following properties.

> 1) $\mu(G) = 1$.
>
> 2) $\mu(E) = \text{sup} \{\mu(K) : K \subset E$, where $K$ is compact$\}$ for every $E \in \mathcal B(G)$.
>
> 3) $\mu(E) = \text{inf} \{\mu(U): E \subset U$, where $U$ is open $\}$ for every $E\in \mathcal B(G)$.
>
> 4) $\mu(aE) = \mu(E)$ whenever $a\in G$ and $E\in \mathcal B(G)$.

Let $\Pi$ be the set of subsets of $G$ that are either the empty set or of the form $aH$, where $a\in G$ and $H$ is an open compact subgroup.
It can be easily proved that $\Pi$ is a [semiring of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring#Semiring_of_sets):
See [Intersection of cosets from possibly distinct subgroups is either empty or a coset of the intersection between the two subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687065/intersection-of-cosets-from-possibly-distinct-subgroups-is-either-empty-or-a-cos)

Define $\lambda(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\lambda(aH) = 1/(G : H)$ where $a\in G$ and $H$ is an open compact subgroup of $G$.

Here are my questions:

> 1) How do you prove that $\lambda$ is finitely additive on $\Pi$. In other words, if $U, U_1, \cdots, U_n \in \Pi$ and $U = \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$ is a disjoint union, how do you prove that $\lambda(U) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda(U_i)$?
>
> 2) How do you construct the Haar measure $\mu$ by using $\lambda$?