# On formula $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/(G : H_i) = 1$ on a group $G$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group.
Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $(G : H) \lt \infty$.
Then there exists a sequence of elements $a_1,\cdots, a_n$ such that 
$G = \bigcup_{i=1}^n a_iH$ is a disjoint union.
Clearly $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/(G : H) = 1$.

Now I would like to generalize this formula.
Suppose there exist a sequence of elements $a_1,\cdots, a_n$ and a sequence of subgroups $H_1,\cdots, H_n$ such that $G = \bigcup_{i=1}^n a_iH_i$ is a disjoint union and $(G : H_i) \lt \infty$ for all $i$.

My question is:

> $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/(G : H_i) = 1$?

Note that $H_1 = \cdots = H_n$ does not generally holds even when $(G : H_1) = \cdots = (G : H_n)$.
See [Finite partition of a group by left cosets of subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413324/finite-partition-of-a-group-by-left-cosets-of-subgroups)

I came up with this problem when trying to explicitly construct Haar measure on a profinite group:
[Explicit construction of Haar measure on a profinite group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412088/explicit-construction-of-haar-measure-on-a-profinite-group)

Here is a train of my thoughts.
Let $G$ be a [profinite group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group).

It is known that every neighborhood of the identity element of $G$ contains an open compact subgroup. Since $G$ is a compact Hausdorff group, there exists a Haar measure $\mu$ on $G$ such that $\mu(G) = 1$. Let $H$ be an open compact subgroup of $G$. Since the set of left cosets $G/H$ is compact and discrete with its quotient topology, $(G : H) \lt \infty$.
Hence there exists a finite sequence of elements $a_1,\cdots, a_n$ such that 
$G = \bigcup_{i=1}^n a_iH$ is a disjoint union.
Then $1 = \mu(G) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(a_iH) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(H) = n\mu(H)$.
Hence $\mu(H) = 1/n = 1/(G : H)$.

Now suppose there exist a sequence of elements $a_1,\cdots, a_n$ and a sequence of open compact subgroups $H_1,\cdots, H_n$ such that $G = \bigcup_{i=1}^n a_iH_i$ is a disjoint union.
Then $1 = \mu(G) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(a_iH_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(H_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n 1/(G : H_i)$.

I wondered if this formula holds on general abstract groups.

Comment: What, precisely, is your question?  Are you asking if the second paragraph is true or for a proof or ...?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: You could take the intersection of all the $H_i$'s and that will give a finite index subgroup.  Then, if you apply the theorem to each $H_i$, you should get your answer.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Would you please make it as an answer so that I could accept it and the thread would be completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H=H_1\cap \cdots\cap H_n$.  By [finite index subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128538/does-the-intersection-of-two-finite-index-subgroups-have-finite-index), the intersection of the $H_i$'s is a finite index subgroup.

Then, $\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{[G:H]}=1.$  Now, however, we can write each $H_i$ as a union of $k_i$ cosets of $H$, so that

$$
1=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{[G:H]}=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{k_i}\frac{1}{[G:H]}=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{k_i}\frac{1}{[G:H_i][H_i:H]}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{[G:H_i]}\sum_{j=1}^{k_i}\frac{1}{[H_i:H]}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{[G:H_i]}
$$
by applying the original statement to each $H_i$.